# Understanding Versioning in .cabal and stack.yaml Files

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

Looking at my stack project's `project.cabal`:

```
name:                project
version:             0.1.0.0
-- synopsis:
-- description:
homepage:            https://github.com/githubuser/project#readme
license:             BSD3
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Author name here
maintainer:          example@example.com
copyright:           2017 Author name here
category:            Web
build-type:          Simple
extra-source-files:  README.md
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable project-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base
                     , project
                     , servant-server
                     , base-compat
                     , wai
                     , aeson
                     , blaze-markup
                     , blaze-html
                     , directory
                     , warp
                     , http-media
                     , lucid
                     , time
                     , bytestring
                     , attoparsec
                     , string-conversions
                     , mtl
                     , servant-lucid
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  ghc-options:
    -fwarn-unused-imports
```

Is it not necessary to specify each library's version? In other words, it seems that I'm only specifying the library, not the version, e.g. `servant-server`.

Looking at my `stack.yaml`, I see:

`resolver: lts-9.5`

Perhaps that version, i.e. `lts-9.5`, specifies the version of each dependency?

In short, I'm asking about versioning in a `stack` project.

Comment: [stack.yaml contains a reference, called a resolver, to the snapshot which your package will be built against](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#what-makes-stack-special)

Answer (score 1):

Correct, it is not necessary to specify the version of a library (in the sense that the parser for `.cabal` files doesn't require it).

Correct, `stack.yaml`'s `lts-9.5` resolver specifies fixed versions of a large swath of Hackage, probably including everything listed in that cabal file. You can see the exact list of package/version pairs implied by `lts-9.5` [on the Stackage website](https://www.stackage.org/lts-9.5).

The community is somewhat divided on which mechanism (version constraints in the `.cabal` file or version constraints by specifying a fixed package/version pair list in `stack.yaml`) is best suited for specifying version bounds, but I think we can unite in agreement that you should use at least one of these two mechanisms. So, while it is technically not necessary to specify version bounds in *any* way, I encourage you to do so in some way despite that. Your project is very likely not to build correctly (either now or at some time in the future) if you leave out version bounds.

Personally, I also consider it best practice to include version bounds *in the `.cabal` file itself*, even if this is just to fix the bounds to exactly what the stackage resolver would choose, so that people who prefer to use cabal for one reason or another will have less trouble with your package.

Comment: "but your project is very likely not to build correctly (either now or at some time in the future) if you leave out version bounds" Why would that be the case? The stack.yaml is fully specifying the versions of all packages being used.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Assuming it gets built with stack, having a `stack.yaml` with a fixed stackage reference does imply that you have included version bounds, just not in the `.cabal` file. But I wanted to address the question asked ("Is it not necessary to specify each library's version?") head-on, addressing the problems that happen if you don't include a version constraint anywhere. I will add a bit of verbiage to be more clear about what I meant here.